# How do I animate this path?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am new to Canvas in HTML5.
I made one path on the canvas, but I want the path to animate and not flash at once. How can I do so ?

below is the JS code ::

```
$('#draw').click(function() {
     var a,b;
     a=b=5;

     context.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

     context.moveTo(centerx, centery);
     context.beginPath();
     context.strokeStyle = "#000"; 
     for (i = 0; i < 120; i++) {
          angle = 0.1 * i;
          x = centerx + (a + b * angle) * Math.cos(angle);
          y = centery + (a + b * angle) * Math.sin(angle);
          context.lineTo(x, y);  
          context.stroke();
      }

 });
```

What I have tried so far:

used `setInterval()`, `setTimeout()` both to no avail. Tried Making different functions for the path rendering and calculation of x and y values but that also did not work ! Also by the documentation, the path is not drawn until `context.stroke()` is called which makes me wonder if it is even possible to animate ?

EDIT:: JSFiddle Link
https://jsfiddle.net/sankh_15A/7L3a4rkL/

Comment: can you post a example fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build an animation you need to recursively draw a piece of your spiral and eventually break out at a certain point.

The most optimized method to draw such animation is `window.requestAnimationFrame` , but you could do it also with `setIterval` or `setTimeout`.

An example would be :

```
var i = 0;
function render(){
   i++;
   angle = 0.1 * i;
   x = centerx + (a + b * angle) * Math.cos(angle);
   y = centery + (a + b * angle) * Math.sin(angle);
   context.lineTo(x, y);  
   context.stroke();
   if (i <720)
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
requestAnimationFrame(render);//start animation
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maio/7L3a4rkL/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much :) I was trying for hours :/

btw can you give me some good link to understand canvas ?